# Knockout image touch event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following code which is working fine on laptop/desktop

```
<img data-bind="click: $root.previewImage, attr:{src: DocFile, data: DocFile}" 
class="card-img-top" alt=""/>

self.previewImage = function (prev) {
    $('#loading').show();

    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(document).width();

    $("#ImgPreview").attr('height', $(window).height() * 0.7);
    $('#ImgPreview').attr('src', ko.toJS(prev.DocFile));

    $('.modal .modal-body').css('max-height', $(window).height() * 0.8);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');

    $('#loading').hide();
};
```

but when I turn into mobile device the click event is not working.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33270519/3082296

Answer (score 0):

Try also adding the "touchend" event.  Keep the "click" binding for desktop browsers, and just add the "touchend" event binding to call the same function that "click" calls.  The end result would look something like this:

```
<img data-bind="click: $root.previewImage, event: { touchend: $root.previewImage }, attr:{src: DocFile, data: DocFile}" class="card-img-top" alt=""/>
```

That should cover you for most mobile browsers.  More info on the "touchend" event (including browser compatibility) can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend).

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comment. but the code that i have posted is working fine. i was misplaced <div> section that's why it was not responding. thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Glad to hear it!